# What should I use to automate server installation every three months ? Puppet, Chef, CFEngine other tips?

Tags: installation, automation

For our department we have a get together every few months where we have presentations but also write code. The locations where the sessions are held differ (not always good internet) and we get a decent server from the IT department to use.  Depending on who is available someone will install a lot of software (windows server, sql server, TFS, Sharepoint, GIT, FTP server) , create local user accounts and in general will get the machine up and running.

It would be nice if we could automate parts of the installation.

I have read a bit about puppet and chef and seen the names of some alternatives that might be useful. But I would really like some advice on what people think is the best solution, but also problems to look for.

Thanks !